# Excel: chart x-axis label

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2016, excel-charts

The current excel *line chart* has the following x-axis labels:

> 2010Q1
>
> 2011Q1
>
> ...
>
> 2016Q1

How could I format the chart so the data from 2010Q1 - 2016Q1 remains, but the labels look like this instead:

> 2010Q2
>
> 2011Q2
>
> ...
>
> 2016Q2

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are looking to do it should be enough to go to axis properties and change label interval to 4.

Comment: I wish it was as simple as this. Rephrasing the question - instead of having the x-axis label start at "2001Q1", I want it to start at "2001Q2".

Answer (score 0):

The quick solution would be to simply edit your data so that you only keep the Q2 labels (in a new column) to be used for the x-axis.